# How should I protect trimmed wires in a push-in connector?

Tags: electrical

I need to reroute the wires to a set of recessed lights. The lights have push-in connectors inside of their junction box.

The wires were cut at the connectors but there are enough extra terminals.

The old wires are trimmed too short to cap or pigtail and I don't want to replace the cans. I'm thinking maybe I paint on liquid electrical tape. Is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: How about a picture Matt

Comment: Are the short wires part of the lamp fixture, or part of the in-wall wiring?

Answer (score 1):

Wires can sometimes be worked out of a push-in connector by twisting and pulling. If the clipped wires cannot be removed because they're too short or won't pull out then replace the whole connector with a new push-on or twist connector.

The clipped wires are sure to have relatively sharp edges somewhere. Like any paint, it's easy to get a thick coating of liquid tape on a smooth surface but it's hard to make it build a good thickness on edges.